# How to write a regex which starts with a given number?

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a program which checks if a string starting with a given number.
Lets say, we have a string: `line = "5p.m. its a lovely time for tea!"` and
then I read a number from user: `num = raw_input()` and want to check if
my line starts with a number that user passed.

I want to do something like (here might be some mistakes):

```
s = compile(r"^[\<%\>]", num)
m = s.search(line)
```

or

```
s = compile(r"^[\<%\>]", num)
m = s.search(line)
```

and when user pass a 5, it will print "OK" or something like that when line
starts with 5, or "Its not OK" when my line starts with a different number.
Im very newbie in this whole regex thing, please, help :) I accept code both for C++ and Python ;)

Comment: do you want a c++ answer, or a python answer? you should not have two programming languages tagged unless it is relevant, i have seen from your comments you want a c++ answer, why did you tag this question as python?

Comment: I think it would be fair to us users to remove the C++ tag to solve for the potential confusion (however, I don't think a downvote is justified here).

Answer (score 5):

Regex is overkill:

```
line = '5p.m. its a lovely time for tea!'
num = raw_input()  # integer input
if line.startswith(num):
    print 'OK'
else:
    print 'It\'s not OK'
```

If you need to use `regex`, you can do this:

```
if re.search('^%s' %num, line):  # checks if there is a match
    print 'OK'
else:
    print 'It\'s not OK'
```

The reason this works is because if there is a match, `re.search` will return an `_sre.SRE_Match object` will evaluate to `True` in a boolean context. If there is no match, it will return `None` will evaluates to `False`.

Comment: yup, I know I can do this but unfortunately, I need to do it with regex :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about c++ and python coding 
but regex that you want is just

```
^(\d).*
```

you can use http://regexpal.com/ to check result

PS. Sorry i try to post image but they don't allow so click the link to see
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwBjJ.png

Comment: `^\d` is sufficient to check. `^(\d)` is sufficient for capturing the digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
number = 5
line = "5p.m. its a lovely time for tea!"
s = compile("^%d" % num)
m = s.search(line)

if m:
  print "time for tea"
```

Comment: Maybe You know how to do the same thing in C++ with boost?

Comment: @yak or try the regex include shipped with c++0x

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

line = "5p.m. its a lovely time for tea!"

match_obj = re.search('^([0-9]+).*', line)

num = raw_input()

if num == match_obj.groups()[0]:

    print "OK"

else:

    print r"It's not ok"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would echo the response above: regex is overkill for this problem.  Use startswith as pointed out above.